# How do I convert a integral over a region R into a double integral using Green's Theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have been given an integral ∫(xdx+2xdy) over the region R defined as the region bounded above by y=ex-x+1 and below by y=e^x, and I have been asked to convert it to a double integral using Green's Theorem. Am I able to interpret the initial integral as being equivalent to a line integral over a path c and use the standard formula for Green's Theorem, or do I need to do something else to get it to that point first?

Comment: The given equations (use $\LaTeX$ to make it unambiguous) don't seem to bound a region; perhaps *'in the first quadrant'* (or with the $y$-axis as additional bound) is meant?

Comment: @StackTD It bounds a very small region between x = 0..1.

Comment: Well then you're using the $y$-axis to bound the region on the left, right...?

Comment: @StackTD Not from what I'm seeing. It's bounded above by the line y=ex-x+1, and below by the exponential curve y=e^x. Note that the line y=ex-x+1 is not y=e^x -x+1.

Comment: Alright, that explains it! I was interpreting it as an exponential (with bad typesetting ;-)). The question is oddly put because you don't calculate a line integral over a region, but over a path. I suppose they mean: over the path that bounds the described region $R$. Green's theorem then turns it into a double integral over that (bounded) region $R$. What exactly are you have trouble with?

Comment: The unusual nature of the problem is where my question comes from. I know that Green's Theorem usually involves a line integral over a path, but it seems unlikely that the problem I was given has a mistake in it. So if I were to interpret what I was given as being an integral over a region R, what process would I have to go through to apply Green's Theorem to it?

Comment: If it's written in the way you copied it here, it is strange in any case. You wrote a single integral in the form of a line integral, that doesn't go "over a region"... But other than that, the problem seems a classical one for Green because the double integral over $R$ is easier to compute than explicitly calculating the (given) line integral over the *boundary of $R$*.

Comment: @StackTD Thanks for the reply. I wanted to see if the problem given as is could be worked with at all (assuming it was written correctly), but if not I'll go ahead and double check if it's supposed to be a line integral when I see my professor again.

Comment: Alright; I gave a short overview in an answer of how the problem was probably meant.

Answer (score 1):

The given region $R$ is bounded by the curve $C$ (consisting of two parts: a piece of the exponential curve and a piece of the straight line) and according to [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem), you then have:
$$\oint_C xdx+2xdy= \iint_R \frac{\partial (2x)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (x)}{\partial y} \, dxdy = \iint_R 2 \, dxdy$$
The region $R$ is easy so the double integral can be calculated as:
$$\iint_R 2 \, dxdy = \int_0^1 \int_{e^x}^{ex-x+1} 2 \, dy \, dx = \ldots = 3-e$$
You could verify this result by explicitly calculating the line integral (in two parts).